# PHP form only posting last value in a series of inputs

Tags: php, forms, button

Attached are pictures of my code. I am trying to pass the index.php value (either 4 or 8) of whichever button named 'num' is clicked to chooseSnacks.php and echo the variable $snacks.

The problem is that it only passes the last valued input in the form (which is 8) no matter if I click on 4 or 8. I reversed the order of the inputs just to double check, and when I did so I could only get the value 4 to pass no matter what I clicked.

Inputs on index.php

```
 <div class="pricing-button">
    <form method="POST" action="ChooseSnacks.php">
       <input class="btn btn-primary btn-md btn-square" onclick="change('19.99')" type="text" value = "4" name="num[]" readonly></a>
       <input class="btn btn-primary btn-md btn-square" onclick="change('25.00')" type="text" value = "8" name="num[]" readonly></a>                                            
 </div>
```

Submit button on index.php

```
 <input class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-square" type="Submit" name="Submit" id="Submit" value='Submit'>
```

Session start on chooseSnacks.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$snacks = $_POST['num[]'];
?>
```

echo the variable

```
 <div class="categories">
  <h3>Your Carepackage</h3>
  <p> <?php echo $snacks; ?> Snacks Every <?php echo $snacksNum; ?> </p> </div
```

[image: Index.php]
[image: chooseSnacks.php]

Comment: Your inputs have the same name so the last one overwrites the others.  Try an array `name="num[]"`

Comment: Do I need to change $snacks = $_POST['num']; to $snacks = $_POST['num[]'];? Because It either sets 'array' or a blank after I try them both

Comment: You need to loop over $snacks and echo.

Comment: mind posting actual code, rather than "images of". The colors are nice 'n all, but serve no real purpose, especially when someone would need to retype all that out.

Comment: Abra I'll try that cheers.

Comment: Fred - done, cheers for the tip.

Comment: Great. Now this `$_POST['num[]'];` you need to remove the `[]` from in there because you already have it in `name="num[]"`. You then just use a `foreach($_POST['num'] as $var)`, should solve it. @ me if you want me to submit as an answer @Nyhan

Comment: @Nyhan I posted an answer below that you can have a look at. That worked for me, if that is the intended result you wish to have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In regards to `$_POST['num[]'];` you need to remove the `[]` from in there, because you already declared them as an array in `name="num[]"`.

You then need to use a `foreach($_POST['num'] as $var)` and checking if they are not empty.

- I used a [ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) for that.

For example:

```
 <div class="pricing-button">
    <form method="POST" action="">
       <input class="btn btn-primary btn-md btn-square" onclick="change('19.99')" type="text" value = "4" name="num[]" readonly></a>
       <input class="btn btn-primary btn-md btn-square" onclick="change('25.00')" type="text" value = "8" name="num[]" readonly></a>

<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">

 </div>


<?php

$inputs = !empty($_POST['num']) ? $_POST['num'] : array();

foreach($inputs as $value) {

   echo $value . "<br>";

}
```

which will echo: (as tested)

```
4
8
```

I'm unsure as to what `onclick="change('19.99')"` etc. is supposed to react as though and the need for sessions where you started the session.

Answer (score 1):

Well your [input type](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type.asp) is `TEXT` so it overrides the last value.
If you want the user to choose an option you should change the type to `RADIO`, OR set the value and name to blank and change it with javascript